# Avoid switch-case condition using design patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a few classes which represent arithmetic operations (Plus, Minus, Pow...) in Java which extend the same abstract class `Operator` but they differ in one method -`calculate`.

I'm trying to find a way to avoid the switch-case conditions in order to implement these classes in the right way using design patterns (new to design patterns), but how do I do it? Or is the switch-case statement is the right way to implement it?

here is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Operator {

    private int a, b;
    
    public Operator(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public float calculate() {
        // here I want to return the result depending on the operator. If Plus extends Operator then the returned value is this.a + this.b
    }
    
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This is the result : %f", this.calculate());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: change `calculate()` to `protected abstract float calculate(int a, int b);` and then call it ? with `this.calculate(a, b)` in your `print()` method, every subclass then has to implement the calculate method and return the result

Comment: You can just make the calculate method abstract and implement it with Plus, Minus, etc.

Comment: What you are talking about is just basic polymorphism. Make calculate abstract. `public abstract float calculate()`. Your fields will need to be protected so that subclasses can use them

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks no need to change the signature (besides adding `abstract`). Just change the fields to protected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there is no need for a design pattern but using polymorphism is enough. Change the Operator class like the following:

```
public abstract class Operator {

    protected int a;
    protected int b;
    
    public Operator(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public abstract float calculate();
    
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This is the result : " + this.calculate());
    }
}
```

And then implement it with Minus and Plus classes:

```
public class Plus extends Operator{
    public Plus(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
    @Override
    public float calculate() {
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}

public class Minus extends Operator{
    public Minus(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
    @Override
    public float calculate() {
        return this.a - this.b;
    }
}
```

This is the class Main for a test:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operator minus = new Minus(5,2);
        minus.print(); // prints: This is the result : 3.0
        Operator plus = new Plus(5,2);
        plus.print();  // prints: This is the result : 7.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see below code:

Change your calculate method to:

```
public float calculate(){
        // here I want to return the result depending on the operator. If Plus extends Operator then the returned value is this.a + this.b
        if(this instanceof Plus ){
            return a + (float)b;
        }else if(this instanceof Minus ){
            return a - (float)b;
        }//...For Mul and Div you can code
        return 0.0f;
    }
```

and after that, you can change your print method to:

```
public void print() {
        System.out.println(String.format("This is the result :  %f", this.calculate()));
    }
```

and after that, you can do call this from any class to get your result:

```
    Operator operator = new Plus(2,5);
    operator.print();
    operator = new Minus(5,2);
    operator.print();
```

Lastly output:

```
This is the result:  7.000000
This is the result:  3.000000
```

Comment: This is not a good way to achieve polymorphism. The list of cases might grow to be very long. Also if someone adds a new operator, they need to be able to edit the base class. The base class might come from a library, or they might otherwise not be able to edit it. Abstract methods are way better for both reasons

Comment: I know, it's not the right way but the question have already concrete method calculate and to complete that there is only this approach that can be done. But abstract is the best way.

Comment: One thing more code need to be within that method as comments speaks something like that **// here I want to return the result depending on the operator. If Plus extends Operator then the returned value is this.a + this.b**